# How did scientists establish the reactions that occur in metabolism?

Tags: metabolism, bioenergetics

How did scientists establish that macromolecules like proteins, carbohydrates and lipids are synthesized from other molecules with intermediate products by living cells. Did they observe this under microscope. I want to know this because I am studying bioenergetics and while studying photosynthesis and cellular respiration I have doubt that whether this all stuff is correct or not. I hope that you will help me to clear this doubt.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The way your question is currently written, it is hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Please also take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What *exactly* do you have a question about? The fields of metabolism and bioenergetics are *huge*, much too broad to be covered in a single question here. Is there something in specific you are unsure about?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to biochemical methods, a lot of this was figured out using radioactive tracers. Cells would be fed a radioactive substrate and as they convert the substrate to other molecules through metabolic reactions, the radioactivity can be detected in the products and intermediates.

Calvin's 1940s-50s experiments to establish carbon flow during photosynthesis (i.e. the Calvin-Benson Cycle) using $^{14}CO_2$ remain some of the most elegant work along these lines. You can actually read some of his reports [here](http://www.osti.gov/accomplishments/calvin.html), though maybe someone else has a good link to a less technical overview.

Similar methods are still used today, though stable isotopes instead of radioactive ones are more commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you do not study metabolism under the microscope. (Modern high resolution microscopes can visualize macromolecular processes like transcription and translation, but that is not how they were studied originally.)

In brief, biochemical pathways were studied in broken cells by studying individual reactions or in whole tissues or animals studying chains of reactions. In broken cells chemical methods (often colorimetric, but historically by measuring the evolution of gases) were used to identify products of reactions when particular chemicals are added, and enzymes purified from tissues to find out what reactions they catalyse. Centrifugation methods were used to different organelles from cells (mitochondria, nuclei, ribosomes). In whole cells radioactive precursors are added and one separates and identifies the compounds in the cell to find out which compounds have acquired radioactivity, i.e. what the original compound has been converted to.

In bioenergetics the methods are/were more specialized using spectrometry to identify the oxygenation state of different cytochromes, and the oxygen electrode to measure the utilization of oxygen. In animal cells isolated mitochondria were often used.

This is a very wide area, although because it is not currently very active it is difficult to find an internet source to recommend you. Perhaps someone else knows of one.